# c# basic anti SQL Injection script

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, security, sql-injection

I have built a web page (ASP.Net C# web-forms) to allow the user to query a database, by selecting their own filtering options.
The users know basic SQL, and know the fields names of the tables they want to query.

I'd like to block as much as possible, any malicious sql command that a user could write.

So the web page is structured with a dropdown list where the users select the table to query, then they can type, in a text box, the where clause. So the server side code that builds the query is:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + DdlTableName.SelectedValue + " WHERE " + TxtWhereClause.Text;
```

The possible security hole is in the last part, i.e they can enter a "*;Drop TableName*"

So I'm trying to eliminate all this possible malicious commands, by searching them in the TxtWhereClause.Text string.

```
public static Boolean checkForSQLInjection(string userInput)
{
    bool isSQLInjection = false;
    string[] sqlCheckList = { "--",";--",";","/*","*/","@@","@"};
    string[] sqlCheckList2 = { " alter ", " create ", " declare ", "delete ", " drop ", " insert ", " select ", " update ", " union " };
    for(int i = 0; i <= sqlCheckList.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if((CheckString.IndexOf(sqlCheckList[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
        { isSQLInjection = true; }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= sqlCheckList2.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if((CheckString.IndexOf(sqlCheckList2[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
        { isSQLInjection = true; }
    }

    return isSQLInjection;
}
```

Keep in mind the the user account used to run this query is a read only account, so I should have no problem at all, but I'd like to insert another layer of security by validating the input.

The above code I've initially written can be easily broken, in example the sqlCheckList2 contains spaces in the words to avoid to mismatch with a field name, **Delete**Date, **Update**dBy, but if I write "(Delete Table..." it will not be blocked by the aabove script.

Do you have any suggestion on how to correctly build that, or there's a library to use?

Obviuosly I can't use **SQLParameter** or **Entity Framework** or any other ORM in this kind of project as the database schema is not fixed and the queries will come from third party systems, where I don't have any control:
the user will write the query to put it inside their own business analysis system that will then query mine passing the **table name** and **where clause** as parameters in the request, and the response will be in **JSON** format (basically it's an **API**). What I've previously described in my question is the web page that will simulate **third party system** that could be everything and out of my control, from a custom webpages to Tableau

Thanks!

Comment: You're better-off implementing your own DSL for specifying boolean logic for filters than trying to sanitise raw SQL. T-SQL is a huge language with many gotchas and a simple exclusion list is insufficient to prevent all malicious activity.

Comment: What's the main reason why you cant use SQLParameter or Entity? There much handy than writing your own logic to filter injections.

Comment: @PrinceJea because the user must be able to apply their own filters and they cannot be planned in advance, also because the schema of this particular database is not fixed and modified by another application. It could sound silly but it's long to explain how it works and why it has this strange architecture. BTW if the SQL user has read-only access is already a good point, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you state that the users only know basic SQL then why not restrict their options through drop down lists / checkbox lists etc? Obviously if they need to write complicated queries then this wouldn't work and certainly wouldn't be safe to allow, but then they would probably know more than basic SQL if they needed to do that.

The first part would be to select the tables needed in the query in a checkbox list or something similar. You can write logic to return the available columns based on their selections.

The second step would be to restrict the actions e.g. select, update, delete etc through a drop down list.

The final step would be to restrict their where clause by forcing the user to select columns via drop downs and to specify the type of their parameters. You can then parameterise these based on what the user has input.

Having said all that, it still seems risky.

***UPDATE***

Based on your final comment it seems you're dealing with a situation that is less than ideal. However, with your current method you're essentially comparing the WHERE clause solely against a black list. This is a risky strategy as it's then assumed that whatever isn't in your black list is ok. It might be better to try and compare against a white list (acceptable values) and therefore deem everything else to be a risk.

Potentially you could go 1 step further and check against the white list first, then a the black list and if something is still not defined as ok or not then it's added to a queue of queries to look at.

Comment: Besides that, users generally can't be bothered to actually go and use tools like this. I've seen it plenty of times before, and the end result always was that the development team were to maintain the queries, so in the end it was better to have the whole thing in code anyway.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I agree. It's normally an idea thought up to try and speed up getting data to various teams like finance or something, but in the end the tools invariably have to be too restrictive (for safety) to allow the users to get the data they want.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @sr28 and CodeCaster but it's not a feasible way in this project. The users are technicians, and the response will be provided in JSON format, so it's not for non-technical people like finance and so on. The queries cannot be hardcoded for several reasons, so that's why I haven't designed a more strict interface

Comment: @Giox - if this is to be used by people who only know basic SQL then why can't it be restrict as per my answer?

Comment: because the user will write the query to put it inside their own analysis system that will then query mine passing the table name and where clause as parameters in the request, and the response will be in JSON format (basically it's an API). 
What I've described in my question is the web page that will simulate third party system that could be everything and out of my control, from a custom webpages to Tableau

Comment: @Giox - ok, that explains that then. It should really be made more clear in the question though.

Answer (score 2):

Please, never try to implement your own solutions for security questions. Use [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid SQL injections or consider Entity Framework instead of classic ADO.NET.

Comment: And how will one implement variable column names in an SqlCommand?

Comment: Actually I don't understand your question. In the ADO.NET you can dynamically add various number of sql parameters based on your own conditions. There is only one restriction _If the parameters in the collection do not match the requirements of the query to be executed, an error may result_

Comment: OP wants to let users build an arbitrary `WHERE` clause, including column names. You cannot parameterize colum names.

Comment: @dimonser Please read the whole question not only the title! I've put it also in bold that is not possible to implement SQLParameter and EF and any other ORM. It's by design, so no change on it.